# What is the audio file in Portal that plays when a radio is destroyed?

Tags: portal

In Portal, there are radios littered throughout the game playing elevator music and encoded transmissions. However, when put one through the [Material Emancipation Grill](https://half-life.fandom.com/wiki/Aperture_Science_Material_Emancipation_Grill), it makes a distorted noise as it disintegrates. I am looking for the audio file for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The disintegration sounds are in (for standard Windows configuration of Steam) `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Portal\portal\portal_pak_dir.vpk`.

This file has a bunch of folders with files used in Portal. I opened it in [GCFScape](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/GCFScape) and found that `dinosaur_fizzle.wav`, `dinosaur_fizzle2.wav`, and `dinosaur_fizzle3.wav`. As seen in [this video](https://youtu.be/oXGgWb5sWN0?t=72) these files were added along with the other radio-related audio to the 2010 update and play when the radio is "emancipated".

The three specific files are in [this Google Drive folder I made](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/10m6j7JupPvs8R7QWsAHZlJvGBmm6HAH1?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find an exact audio file for it from the game files (although maybe someone can find it with more time).

I did manage to record the sound of the radio being destroyed by an Emancipation Grill.

I'll leave the link right [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17Lkke5gTmi5MmlhbJ7evaIBfzONzQVHv/view?usp=sharing)

*you might have to cut off some extra sounds, unless you wish to keep them*